How does SQL Server store integer values of over 2^24 in a FLOAT(53) column?
I have a SQL Server database from which I can read integer values of (way) over 2^24 from a column that has datatype float. This confuses me since these values should be to big/lengthy to be accurately represented as a float. I managed to create a reproduction in my local DB.
To the best of my knowledge, 16777216 (=2^24) and 16777217 should have the same binary floating point representation. They are both mapped to 0 10010111 00000000000000000000000.
Now consider this:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS F_ING_FLOATS;
CREATE TABLE F_ING_FLOATS (COL FLOAT(53));

INSERT INTO F_ING_FLOATS
    VALUES (16777216), (16777217);

Since I expect that both value are mapped to the same float, I would als expect that the distinction between the two is lost in the DB. However, the query
SELECT 
    COL, 
    COL + 1 [COL + 1],
    COL + 2 [COL + 2] 
FROM 
    F_ING_FLOATS;

annoyingly returns the correct values:
COL         COL + 1     COL + 2
------------------------------------------
16777216    16777217    16777218
16777217    16777218    16777219

I had expected to see 16777216 everywhere in the first two columns and 16777218 in both rows of the last column.
What is happening here that is beyond my grasp? Is SQL Server not actually storing 32-bit floating points, even though I defined COL FLOAT(53)?

The reason this is a problem for me, is that the values from the SQL Server DB get loaded into parquets into an Azure datalake. The in the datalake I see exactly what I expect: COL has two rows, both with value 16777216.
I'm in the process of understanding what is actually happening. And my suspicion is that SQL Server is not entirely honest when it says that COL is FLOAT(53).

To further elaborate on my confusion: I use this online converter to find out what the internal representation is. It tells me that 16777216 and 16777217 have the same representation, which should explain why the parquets in my datalake can't distinguish them (or at least I think it explains it).

"This confuses me since these values should be to big/lengthy to be accurately represented as a float." The problem is you assume SQL Server will store the value accurately when you get to figures that large. The documentation clearly states the value is an "Approximate-number data type"; once you start getting to very small/large value, you will lose accuracy. If you want accurate figures, float is never the correct choice; base-2 and base-10 numbers don't "play nice".

@ThomA, am I not saying explicitly that I do not expect accurately stored values? I know floats are approximations and I expect these two integers to have the same approximation.

Also, float is accurate to 15 digits, not 8. It's 8 bytes in size, which is 64 bits. real (float(24)) is 32 bits.

The internal representation typically follows the IEEE 754 standard. Despite the name float, with 53 bits it is double precision.  And with 53 bits of precision, you can get up to 2⁵³ = 9007199254740992 before you start to lose digits to the left of the decimal point.

@SteveSummit, I see. So I incorrectly assumed the numbers would be saved to 32 bit. They are actually stored in 64 bit, wich explains why they are distinguishable. The problem with my copy in the datalake is then probably just that: SQL Server uses double and the datalake uses single precision.

@ThomA, would you agree with my last comment?

I don't know anything about data lake, @gebruiker , so it's impossible for me to comment.

@gebruiker "...I expect these two integers to have the same approximation..." -- Don't expect that a approximate data type will manage exact accuracy. Even if it works well today, it may not work in the next version of the database. I would not base business logic on such an assumption.

For FLOAT(53), SQL uses the IEEE-754 binary64 format, which has a 53-bit significand. That format can distinguish 16,777,216 and 16,777,217.
For FLOAT(24), the binary32 format would be used, and that format cannot distinguish 16,777,216 and 16,777,217 because it cannot represent 16,777,217.
(Note that 16,777,216 and 16,777,217 do not “have the same binary floating point representation.” Rather, 16,777,217 does not have any representation at all. What happens is that, when 16,777,217 is converted to the binary32 format, from text or from another numerical format, a rounded result is produced. The result is exactly 16,777,216; it is not a representation of 16,777,217. This distinction is crucial for correct analysis, understand, design, and proofs of floating-point operations. The operations, including conversion, approximate real-number operations, but the represented values are exact.)

This is an excelent explanation. Do you know if the rounding is dependable. I.e. can I safely assume that 16,777,217 is always rounded down when converted to bin32, or can it just as well be rounded up to 16,777,218?

@gebruiker: Round-to-nearest ties-to-even is fully specified by IEEE 754; the result is always the same in all implementations that conform to IEEE 754. The round-to-nearest ties-to-even method is used as the default in almost all floating-point implementations, but I do not know what SQL specifies about whether it must be used.
